# Navigation Title is not well aligned and the navbar is a bit too thick?

Tags: python, html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason the title is not properly aligned and the navbar is too thick?
How will I be able to let it show properly aligned and smaller size?

I am sure it can be done using Bootstrap itself, without additional css, right?

*Sorry, I can't post the image directly here, need higher reputation.*
[Screenshot of the navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYjle.png)

```html
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}">
    
    <!-- This link is just added for support on StackOverflow. -->
    <link href="http://157.97.56.42:8000/static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
    
    <style>
        html, body {
            margin-top: 65px;
        }
    </style>

    {% block base.head %}
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block base.header %}
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <span class="navbar-brand">Developity</span>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="/index" class="navbar-text">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/projects" class="navbar-text">Projects</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    {% endblock %}

    {% block base.body %}
    {% endblock %}

    {% block base.footer %}
    {% endblock %}

    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
    
    <!-- This link is just added for support on StackOverflow. -->
    <script src="http://157.97.56.42:8000/static/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://157.97.56.42:8000/static/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any custom CSS?

Comment: Only CSS, what's in the code already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the navbar-text class will remove the margin from the links making the navbar smaller and everything aligned.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <span class="navbar-brand">Developity</span>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="/index">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/projects">Projects</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Or you can add navbar-text to the navbar-brand to give it the same margins as the links.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <span class="navbar-brand navbar-text">Developity</span>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">   
    <li><a href="/index" class="navbar-text">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/projects" class="navbar-text">Projects</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Both shown here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RpvYba

Comment: Very thank you, it does work, but how can I add tabs/pils?

Comment: There's no built in nav-brand class for the nav-pills and nav-tabs classes. But you can just make your own in that case. For vertical alignment you can line it up by matching the line height of the brand to the height of the nav. Added example to codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RpvYba